# jQuery - Disabling and Enabling Form Elements with Buttons

Tags: jquery, javascript

Hey all, thanks in advance for the help.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showexistingcust").button().click(function () {
        $('#newcust :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#newcust :select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#existingcust :input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#existingcust :select').removeAttr('disabled');
    })

    $("#showaddcust").button().click(function () {
        $('#existingcust :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#existingcust :select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#newcust :input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#newcust :select').removeAttr('disabled');
    })
});
```

I'm pretty new to jquery, so I might be missing something basic. But this seems to have some odd behavior. Depending on how I order to the code, the removeAttr functions either dont run at all, or just work on one button/div.

I have no idea why this is so, anybody able to shed some light?

EDIT: The HTML:

```
<div id="newcust">
<label for="surname" class="left">Surname</label> 
<input type="text" name="surname" id="s_name" class="required" /><br />

<label for="p_name" class="left">Personal Name</label> 

<input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" class="required"/> <br />

<label for="m_phone" class="left">Mobile Phone</label> 
<input type="text" name="m_phone" id="m_phone" class="digits"/> <br />

<label for="h_phone" class="left">Home Phone</label> 
<input type="text" name="h_phone" id="h_phone" class="digits"/> <br />

<label for="w_phone" class="left">Work Phone</label> 
<input type="text" name="w_phone" id="w_phone" class="digits"/> <br />

<label for="email" class="left">Email Addresss</label> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" /> <br />

<label for="address1" class="left">Addresss</label> 
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"/> <br />

<label for="address2" class="blank">Address</label>
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" class="required"/> <br />

<label for="suburb" class="left">Suburb</label> 
<input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" class="required"/> 
<br />

<label for="postcode" class="left">Postcode</label> 
<input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="digits required" maxlength="4"/> <br />

<label for="state" class="left">State</label> 
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="required" maxlength="3"/> <br />

<label for="paytype" class="left">Prefered Payment Type</label>
<select name="paytype" class="required">
<option value="cash">Cash</option>
<option value="credit">Credit Card</option>
</select> <br />
<label for="promo" class="left">Promotional Material</label>    
<input type="checkbox" name="promo" value="1" /><br />
</div>

<div id="existingcust">
<label for="searchc">Search</label>
<input type="text" name="searchc" id="searchc_box" class='searchc_box'/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchc_button" id="searchc_button" /> <br />
<label for="c">Results</label>
<select name="custlist" id="custlist" class="required">
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by omitting the actions on `select` elements, the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector matches `select` as well as `input`, `textarea`, and `button` elements.   Try returning false from the handler to prevent it from taking the default action (I assume these are anchor tags being made into buttons).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showexistingcust").button().click(function () {
        $('#newcust :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#existingcust :input').removeAttr('disabled');
        return false;
    })

    $("#showaddcust").button().click(function () {
        $('#existingcust :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#newcust :input').removeAttr('disabled');
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Wow, i removed the select tags as you said and it worked. Thanks