# enabling - disabling form elements checking - unchecking checkbox input jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to enable all form elements when checking a checkbox form element. And reverse.
This is my code (which doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#coments input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#coments textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#coments select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#coments input[type=submit]').hide();

    $('#coments input[type:checkbox]').click(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);

        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            $('#coments input[type=submit]').show();
            $('#coments textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#coments select').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#coments input[type=text]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#coments input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#coments textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#coments select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#coments input[type=submit]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope any of you can help!

Comment: duplicate of many many questions on this site. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059009/jquery-disabling-and-enabling-form-elements-with-buttons?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For textboxes and textarea's you need to set the "readonly" attribute

```
$('#coments textarea').attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for your reply. I've tried $('#coments textarea').attr("disabled", "disabled") and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I beg your pardon for wasting your time! I have already detected a syntaxis mistake that was breaking my head.
The line:
    $('#coments input[type:checkbox]').click(function() {...
should be:
    $('#coments input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {...
Sorry again and thanks anyway.